# Synchronizing master/slave model with MPI

Tags: c, synchronization, mpi, master-slave

i have an issue with synchronizing Master/slaves processes using MPI.
I wish that the master control the order of the execution of the slaves. Eeach slave have to do : 1- read 2-process. 
Here is my code :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv []){

int rank,numprocess;

MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
MPI_Comm_rank( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank );
MPI_Comm_size( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocess );


if(rank==0){ //master

    MPI_Status s;int Sstate=1;int Rstate;

    int p;
    for(p=1;p<numprocess;p++){

        fflush(stdout);printf("master : order P%d to start reading\n",p);
        MPI_Send(&Sstate, sizeof(int), MPI_INT, p, 20, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Recv(&Rstate,sizeof(int),MPI_INT,p,21,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&s);
        fflush(stdout);printf("master : P%d finished reading\n",p);
    }

}
else{ //workers

    int state; MPI_Status s;
    MPI_Recv(&state,sizeof(int),MPI_INT,0,20,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&s);

    //read here
    Sleep(1000);

    //send to master : finish reading
    state=2;
    MPI_Send(&state, sizeof(int), MPI_INT, 0, 21, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    //processing
    Sleep(3000);
    fflush(stdout);printf("worker %d ended processing\n",rank);
}

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

My probleme is with the last process. In fact it didn't act like the others. here is my output :

```
mpiexec -n 4 master.exe
master : order P1 to start reading 
master : p1 finished reading
master : order P2 to start reading 
master : p2 finished reading
master : order P3 to start reading 
worker 1 ended processing 
worker 2 ended processing 
master : p3 finished reading
worker 3 ended processing
```

Why the third process is not synchronized? 
Thank you for precious help!

Comment: Why do you think it is not synchronized?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you've shown is *Normal* for a multi-threaded or multi-process architecture. Basically, after your processes call `MPI_Send` to the master process, they are released to function on their own as they have no more blocking MPI calls. Thus after they sleep they print their end statement, *independently from one another and the master itself!*

Below I have a diagram which I hope will illustrate what you're seeing:

[image: Prints happen independently]

Comment: Thank you very mush for that clear diagram. It's exactly what i want to do.
The problem that the P3 is printing ("finished reading") after 3 seconds of the printing by P2. However i wanted them to act as following : 
1- p1 finish reading
after 1 second 
2- P2 finish reading
after 1 second 
3- p3 finish reading
after x seconds 
4 Pi ennded process (i=:1..3)

Comment: You want them all to wait until they all finish?

Comment: in fact i want to be sure that processing is performed in parallel. However i want to synchronize the reading so on process read at a time. Since processing is a parallel task, i wish that P1 read and then start process. At the same time when p1 start processing, p2 should start reading. And so on.

Comment: That *is* what is going on here as far as I can see from the console output. If you consider the `Sleep = 1s` step to be "read from a file", only one process is doing so at a time.

Comment: yes in fact after measuring the time of real application (processing a 4 Go file) it was weel synchronized. There is no extra time. So i assume that's ok. I really want to thank you for your help.

Comment: off-topic, which software did you use to draw this nice-looking diagram?

Comment: @takwing: Visio 2010 -> Flowchart -> Swimlane.

Answer (score 1):

Your output is to be expected. You have synchronized the read part of your slave processes, but have not done anything to synchronize the processing part of your slaves. Your slaves will read in order (P1, then P2, then P3), but nothing constraints the order in which processing is done. Also, a process may start processing, before the next processes finished reading.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
Actually, i assume that processing is done in parallel. However, reading from the disk is serial (mutual exlusion). I expected to have :
1- order p1 to start 
(wait 1 second, processing should had began)
2- order p2 to start 
(wait 1 second, processing should had began)
3- order p3 to start 
(after 1 second and the rest of processing time)
4- pi finished (i:1..3)

Comment: @ezzakrem: reading from a file is not a process-serial operation for userspace applications without locking.

Comment: Could you draw a Gantt diagram to better illustrate this?